# Arquillian JUnit Testsuite

Tags: java, junit, junit4, jboss-arquillian

I was wondering if Arquillian supports Test Suites since it's not documented. I would like to create a common deployment for my suite and let the tests of that suite run with that single deployment.

I tried to put the deployment method to the testsuite and also in a testcase with an empty test method to somehow get that working, but it seems like arquillian tries to deploy an artifact for each testcase.

Is there a way to achieve that behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly test suites are not yet supported, but they are [on the roadmap](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-567).

Comment: Thanks, I hope that this feature will be added soon!

Answer (score 4):

I pushed extenson made by it-crowd a bit further bu adding annotation to point deployment providing class and making "generic" builder for projects.

https://github.com/ingwarsw/arquillian-suite-extension

Comment: Wau, it was really easy to make it run! Simple but great documentation. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ingwar unable to use https://github.com/ingwarsw/arquillian-suite-extension  do you have a sample project showing implementation of The Arquillian Suite Extension

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late to help Christian but hopefully it can help anyone looking to do the same thing.

There is an unofficial extension that will achieve the functionality Christian was after. see: https://github.com/it-crowd/arquillian-suite-extension